# MomentFromNow return wrong result in moment.js

Tags: angularjs, localization, momentjs, aspnetboilerplate, windows-server-2016

I have this filter

```
angular.module('app')
.filter('momentFromNow', function () {
    return function (input) {
        return moment(input).fromNow();
    };
});
```

and Abp.Localization.CultureName value in cookie is "fa-IR" . but momentFromNow filter return value for example is "2 minutes ago", it is expected to be "2 دقیقه پیش". how can I fix this problem.
My project template is aspnetboilerplate+SPA+ASP.Net MVC5x 
after 3 hour work: 
if site hosted in windows Server2012R2 it work properly but in WindowsServer2016 not.
any solution?

Comment: it seems related to dotnetversion>4.6.1

Answer (score 1):

you need to change locale of your moment
add a script tag to your `layout.cshtml`

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        abp.localization.currentCulture = $.extend({}, abp.localization.currentCulture, { displayNameEnglish: '@CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.EnglishName' });
        moment.locale('@(CultureHelper.UsingLunarCalendar ? "en": CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name )'); //Localizing moment.js
    </script>
```

---

alternatively you can change local like below:

```
moment.locale('fr', {
    months : 'janvier_février_mars_avril_mai_juin_juillet_août_septembre_octobre_novembre_décembre'.split('_'),
    monthsShort : 'janv._févr._mars_avr._mai_juin_juil._août_sept._oct._nov._déc.'.split('_'),
    monthsParseExact : true,
    weekdays : 'dimanche_lundi_mardi_mercredi_jeudi_vendredi_samedi'.split('_'),
    weekdaysShort : 'dim._lun._mar._mer._jeu._ven._sam.'.split('_'),
    weekdaysMin : 'Di_Lu_Ma_Me_Je_Ve_Sa'.split('_'),
    weekdaysParseExact : true,
    longDateFormat : {
        LT : 'HH:mm',
        LTS : 'HH:mm:ss',
        L : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        LL : 'D MMMM YYYY',
        LLL : 'D MMMM YYYY HH:mm',
        LLLL : 'dddd D MMMM YYYY HH:mm'
    },
    calendar : {
        sameDay : '[Aujourd’hui à] LT',
        nextDay : '[Demain à] LT',
        nextWeek : 'dddd [à] LT',
        lastDay : '[Hier à] LT',
        lastWeek : 'dddd [dernier à] LT',
        sameElse : 'L'
    },
    relativeTime : {
        future : 'dans %s',
        past : 'il y a %s',
        s : 'quelques secondes',
        m : 'une minute',
        mm : '%d minutes',
        h : 'une heure',
        hh : '%d heures',
        d : 'un jour',
        dd : '%d jours',
        M : 'un mois',
        MM : '%d mois',
        y : 'un an',
        yy : '%d ans'
    },
    dayOfMonthOrdinalParse : /\d{1,2}(er|e)/,
    ordinal : function (number) {
        return number + (number === 1 ? 'er' : 'e');
    },
    meridiemParse : /PD|MD/,
    isPM : function (input) {
        return input.charAt(0) === 'M';
    },
    // In case the meridiem units are not separated around 12, then implement
    // this function (look at locale/id.js for an example).
    // meridiemHour : function (hour, meridiem) {
    //     return /* 0-23 hour, given meridiem token and hour 1-12 */ ;
    // },
    meridiem : function (hours, minutes, isLower) {
        return hours < 12 ? 'PD' : 'MD';
    },
    week : {
        dow : 1, // Monday is the first day of the week.
        doy : 4  // Used to determine first week of the year.
    }
});
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/